# How to make absolute URL without character conversion?

Tags: c#, url

There are already similar questions on SO and the answer is this:

```
new Uri(new Uri(base_url),relative_url);
```

However this is not the correct answer, because it converts characters. Consider you have relative url such as:

```
hello%2Fworld.html
```

This is valid url, when you run above code you will get a page `hello/world.html`, which technically is valid, but it is useless because it is unlikely server hosts 2 copies of the page with both URLs.

Before I write my own custom function for combining URLs, is there any existing function which combines URLs and does **NOT** do any conversion?

---

My current solution is based on "discovery" that character conversion is done depending on the scheme. For ftp protocol the characters are preserved. Since it is a bit of hackery I also made sure I won't be surprised by change of that behaviour in the future. My code is below:

```
public static class UrlIO
{
    public static string Combine(string baseUrl, string relativeUrl)
    {
        const string ftp = "ftp";

        var scheme = new Uri(baseUrl).Scheme;
        return scheme + new Uri(new Uri(ftp + baseUrl.DeleteStart(scheme)), relativeUrl).AbsoluteUri.DeleteStart(ftp);
    }

    static UrlIO()
    {
        #if DEBUG
        Assert.AreEqual("ftp://foobar.com/hello_world.html", UrlIO.Combine("ftp://foobar.com/", "/hello_world.html"));
        Assert.AreEqual("ftp://foobar.com/hello_world.html", UrlIO.Combine("ftp://foobar.com/xxx", "/hello_world.html"));
        Assert.AreEqual("ftp://foobar.com/xxx/hello_world.html", UrlIO.Combine("ftp://foobar.com/xxx/", "hello_world.html"));
        Assert.AreEqual("ftp://foobar.com/xxx/hello%2Fworld.html", UrlIO.Combine("ftp://foobar.com/xxx/", "hello%2Fworld.html"));
        Assert.AreEqual("http://foobar.com/xxx/hello%2Fworld.html", UrlIO.Combine("http://foobar.com/xxx/index.html", "hello%2Fworld.html"));
        #endif
    }
}
```

Please change `DeleteStart` extension method to something you have in your library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following extension method for this. add this in static class.

Usage,

```
string fullUrl=relative_url.ConvertToFullUrl();
```

Extension method,

```
public static string ConvertToFullUrl(this string relativeUrl)
{
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(relativeUrl, UriKind.Absolute))
    {
        if (!relativeUrl.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            relativeUrl = relativeUrl.Insert(0, "/");
        }
        if (relativeUrl.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            relativeUrl = relativeUrl.Substring(1);
        }

        return string.Format(
            "{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == 80 ? "" : ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port.ToString(),
            relativeUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so custom function after all :-) I will wait a bit with accepting your answer, maybe someone come up with existing function. I hope you don't mind.